# changing user prompt terminal

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh

I am new to using macs. I was using the `bash` shell, but recently tried switching to using iTerm2 and `zsh`. Originally, it looked the way I wanted, but something changed and reformatted my shell.

Basically I want my user prompt when it opens to look like this... I want to go back to the original iterm2 and zsh defaults

https://draculatheme.com/iterm/

Instead of the `->` , my terminal has `Username@PCname: ~%`

**Edit**

ECHO $SHELL gives

```
/bin/bash
```

more /etc/shells outputs:

```
List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Would adding `PROMPT='%F{magenta}->'` to your `.zshrc` work for you?

Comment: Didn't work. Can I start over? E.g. start from the bash shell that comes with the terminal , uninstall iterm and zsh and then reinstall?

Comment: Reinstalling won't delete any config files like .zshrc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your shell is currently set to bash.

From the iTerm2 profiles menu select open profiles. Now you can either create a new profile or modify the default. If you click edit profile this will bring up a preferences window. On this configuration window you can set the "Command" to /bin/zsh.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: If you create a new profile you'll need to set it as default or access it from the Profile menu. Otherwise a solid answer.